# Is there a way to change several textbox's readonly attribute programatically

Tags: .net

Is there a way to change several textbox's readonly attribute programatically in .net.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your textboxes all begin with the same prefix and exist in the page controls collection:

```
string commonTextBoxPrefix = "txt";
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
    if (c.GetType() == typeof(TextBox) &&
        c.Name.StartsWith(commonTextBoxPrefix))
    {
        ((TextBox)c).ReadOnly = True;
    }
}
```

This will not recurse the entire control hierarchy though :)

Answer (score 0):

You could load them as an array and change them with a loop

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

```
txt.Attributes["ReadOnly"] = "true";
```

Just use a loop for that :)

or you haven't that attribute in your controls tags.

you can either use that code

```
txt.Attributes.Add("ReadOnly","true");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could load the names of the textboxes into a list and change them that way, or load the textbox objects into a list and change them.

```
foreach(TextBox txt in List<TextBox>)
{
    txt.ReadOnly = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is.

Add each textbox to an array, and then loop through the array changing the attributes.

For example:

```
Dim textBoxes() As TextBox = {TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3}
For Each item As TextBox In textBoxes
    item.ReadOnly = True
Next
```